# How can I remove old Files in .camel Subfolder?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I use a File-Endpoint to read files. After Camel reads the file it moves the file to the subfolder .camel. So thats OK, and thats what I want. But after some months there are thousends of files.

It is possible to remove automaticly files older than x weeks? Without external tools? Is there an option for the File-endpoint? I don't find anything.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no such support or tool. Usually you move files to some backup folder, and then you have some other system that takes care of house keeping those files.

It's not suitable to let Camel monitor for files older than X and delete them, even though you can build a route doing that.

Often your sys admins have their own way of managing their infrastructure.